# Split ArrayList into multipleList based on the value in the list

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having an arraylist of MyObjects in which i want to split my list based on the title value of my object.For Example

```
List<MyProduct> productList = instance.getMyProductList();
```

this is my list containing many products.

```
product = productList.get(i);
String tittle = product.getTitle();
```

I want to split my arraylist into several list which is having similar product title.

Please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I tried to compare the current value with the previous value but it looks complex since the list is coming from server and may subject to change

Comment: How do you define "similar product title"?

Comment: Just show us what you already have

Comment: product = productList.get(i);
      if(productList.size()!=1){
       if(product.getProductTitle()== prevProductTitle){
        categoryList.add(product);
       }else{
        newCategoryList = new ArrayList<MyProduct>();
        newCategoryList.add(product);
       }
      }

Comment: I am getting the list of movies from the server with category for each movie.So i want to split my list based on the category of the movie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Guava:

```
ListMultimap<String, MyProduct> result = Multimaps.index(productList, new Function<String, Product>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(Product input) {
        return input.getTitle();
    }
});
```

With plain old Java collections:

```
Map<String, List<MyProduct>> result = new HashMap<>();
for (MyProduct p : productList) {
    List<MyProduct> list = result.get(p.getTitle());
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        result.put(p.getTitle(), list);
    }
    list.add(p);
}
```

Both assume that a "similar" title is actually an "equal" title.

Comment: For suppose I am having 5 different title,so how can I access the 5 different list?

Comment: Have you at least looked at the [javadoc for Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)? `List<MyProduct> productsWithTitleFoo = result.get("foo");`. `Collection<List<MyProduct>> allListsOfProducts = result.values();`